# Getting 403 on post request

Tags: angular, post

**Angular 11**

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vunq3e

Im trying to make a post request in order to mark liked tracks:

**Services.ts**

```
MarklikedSongs(id:any, status:boolean){
    const token = "1072694e";
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      
      "user-access-token": token
    });
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers
    };
    return this.http.post(`https://api.sprintt.co/spotify/liked_tracks/${id}?status=${status}`, httpOptions);
 
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
markLikedSongs(id:any){
    this.playListsAPI.MarklikedSongs(id,true).subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.likedSongs = data
      console.log(" this.likedSongs:",  this.likedSongs)
    })
  }
```

For unknown reason, I get an 403 error message when trying to make a request from the **client side**:
**"token is not recognized"**, or more precisely, the token is not even sent to the headers.
although everything checks out in Postman and in my other motheds..

[image]

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the user-access-token in your screenshot of your dev tools under request headers

Comment: Thats the problem,the token isnt sent to the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are passed in the Authorization header.

Try this: Replace you token with auth_token.

```
 const headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`
  });
```

Comment: Still nothing...Added a working stackblitz to the post.